# response code 401 occur while tweet on twitter via php code

Tags: php

I have to implement Twitter integration into an application in which I have to send tweets. I am using the following code but I get a response code 401 when executed.

How can I send a tweet to Twitter using PHP?

```
 <?php

    $tweet_text = 'Hello Twitter';

    print "Posting...\n";

    $result = post_tweet($tweet_text);

    print "Response code: " . $result . "\n";

    function post_tweet($tweet_text) {

      require_once('tmhOAuth.php');

      $connection = new tmhOAuth(array(
        'consumer_key' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        'consumer_secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        'user_token' => 'xxxxxx-xxx',
        'user_secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        'curl_ssl_verifypeer'   => false
      ));

      $connection->request('POST',
        $connection->url('1/statuses/update'),
        array('status' => $tweet_text));

      return $connection->response['code'];
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: don't share your consumer_key and secret key in public

Comment: Can you please provide your errors more specifically

Comment: response code 401 occur credential missing

Comment: i use only this code and on other credential i give

Answer (score 0):

response code 401 shows when you are not authorized to do the action. You may have given wrong credentials, possibly a typo mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Is this your complete code to post a Tweet to the API? If so,then where are you getting the `user_token` and `user_secret` from?

Because the error is `401 Unauthorized` then I suspect this may be the case.

You may possibly need to investigate [OAuth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth), which is a multi step process between your code and the Twitter API.